# Joining data frames by taking one column and adding it to a row

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my first post. If I violate any procedures or such please let me know and I will improve myself accordingly. I am relatively new to R, so I am reading books on it constantly and havent been able to solve this issue.

I have multiple data frames that I am working on combining. There is a lot of employee data. I'm tying to make one master data frame with all of our data about each person (each row is all the information on a single employee). For one of our data frames its already set up this way.

The greater issue occurs from our HR file. We have an entry every time there is an HR "event". So you get a raise, you move departments, a data correction, etc. To give a basic idea it looks kinda like this:

```
Employee ID      Event      
1                Pay Raise
1                Promotion
1                Transfer
2                Data Cor
3                Raise
3                New Sup
```

I want to combine it with a data frame that looks like this

```
`Employee ID     Hire Date      Salary
1               1/2/06         50000
2               4/6/15         100000
3               7/23/97        120000`
```

I want to add columns at the end, using Employee ID to match. So basically this is the expected result:

```
Employee ID     Hire Date    Salary   Event 1   Event 2   Event 3
 1               1/2/06       50000    Raise     Promotion Transfer
 2               4/6/15       100000   Data Cor  NA        NA
 3               7/23/97      120000   Raise     New Sup   NA
```

Comment: Hi @Xanman, you've received some good answers below, please consider accepting the solution that solved your issue. This lets the community know the answer worked and that the issue is closed.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but how do I close it out?

Comment: thanks for asking. You can accept an answer that was most helpful to you by clicking on the check mark to the left of that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected result requires two operations:

- reshape the events file from long to wide format
- join with the other employee base data from the HR file

This can be achieved in a "one-liner" using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
dcast(setDT(events), Employee_ID ~ paste0("Event_", rowid(Employee_ID)))[
  setDT(employees), on = "Employee_ID"]
```

> ```
>    Employee_ID   Event_1   Event_2  Event_3 Hire_Date Salary
> 1:           1 Pay Raise Promotion Transfer    1/2/06  50000
> 2:           2  Data Cor        NA       NA    4/6/15 100000
> 3:           3     Raise   New Sup       NA   7/23/97 120000
> 4:           4        NA        NA       NA    1/8/17  40000
> ```

Note that I've deliberately added a fourth employee to simulate the situation where no event has been recorded yet for an employee.

As the OP has requested *to add columns at the end*, `setcolorder()` is used to change the column order *in place* which avoids copying the whole data object:

```
dcast(setDT(events), Employee_ID ~ paste0("Event_", rowid(Employee_ID)))[
  setDT(employees), on = "Employee_ID"][
    , setcolorder(.SD, c(names(employees), setdiff(names(.SD), names(employees))))]
```

> ```
>    Employee_ID Hire_Date Salary   Event_1   Event_2  Event_3
> 1:           1    1/2/06  50000 Pay Raise Promotion Transfer
> 2:           2    4/6/15 100000  Data Cor        NA       NA
> 3:           3   7/23/97 120000     Raise   New Sup       NA
> 4:           4    1/8/17  40000        NA        NA       NA
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness, here is a less efficient alternative where the join is done *before* reshaping from long to wide format:

```
setDT(events)[setDT(employees), on = "Employee_ID"][
  , dcast(.SD, Employee_ID + ... ~ paste0("Event_", rowid(Employee_ID)), 
          value.var = "Event")]
```

> ```
>    Employee_ID Hire_Date Salary   Event_1   Event_2  Event_3
> 1:           1    1/2/06  50000 Pay Raise Promotion Transfer
> 2:           2    4/6/15 100000  Data Cor        NA       NA
> 3:           3   7/23/97 120000     Raise   New Sup       NA
> 4:           4    1/8/17  40000        NA        NA       NA
> ```

Although this requires less effort in terms of coding because the columns are returned in the expected order without an additional call to `setcolorder()` it is likely to be less efficient in terms of memory consumption and speed if `employee` has many columns. The OP has mentioned that *each row is **all** the information on a single employee* (emphasis mine).

#### Data

```
events <- readr::read_table(
  "Employee_ID      Event      
  1                Pay Raise
  1                Promotion
  1                Transfer
  2                Data Cor
  3                Raise
  3                New Sup")
employees <- readr::read_table(
  "Employee_ID     Hire_Date      Salary
1               1/2/06         50000
2               4/6/15         100000
3               7/23/97        120000
4               1/8/17         40000")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the inputs defined in the Note below, define `Seq` which is "Event 1" for the first row of an employee in `DF1`, "Event 2" for the second and so on.  Then use `tapply` to convert `DF1` from long form to wide form using `Seq`.   Replace any empty strings with NA and then merge it with `DF1`.  No packages are used.

```
Seq <- paste("Event", ave(1:nrow(DF1), DF1$"Employee ID", FUN = seq_along))
wide <- with(DF1, tapply(Event, list(`Employee ID`, Seq), c))
wide[wide == ""] <- NA
merge(DF2, wide, by.x = 1, by.y = 0, all.x = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  Employee ID Hire Date Salary   Event 1   Event 2  Event 3
1        Emp1    1/2/06  50000 Pay Raise Promotion Transfer
2        Emp2    4/6/15 100000  Data Cor      <NA>     <NA>
3        Emp3   7/23/97 120000     Raise   New Sup     <NA>
```

**Note:** The inputs in reproducible form are:

```
Lines1 <- "
Employee ID,Event      
Emp1,Pay Raise
Emp1,Promotion
Emp1,Transfer
Emp2,Data Cor
Emp3,Raise
Emp3,New Sup"
DF1 <- read.csv(text = Lines1, check.names = FALSE, as.is = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "
Employee ID,Hire Date,Salary
Emp1,1/2/06,50000
Emp2,4/6/15,100000
Emp3,7/23/97,120000"
DF2 <- read.csv(text = Lines2, as.is = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Your data

```
library(data.table)

DF1 <- fread("Employee_ID,Event
1,Pay Raise
1,Promotion
1,Transfer
2,Data Cor
3,Raise
3,New Sup", header=T, sep=",")

DF2 <- fread("Employee_ID,Hire_Date,Salary
1,1/2/06,50000
2,4/6/15,100000
3,7/23/97,120000", header=T, sep=",")
```

#### dplyr & tidyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result <- DF1 %>% 
            group_by(Employee_ID) %>% 
            summarise(dummy=paste0(Event,collapse=",")) %>% 
            separate(dummy, into=c("Event_1","Event_2","Event_3"), sep=",", extra="drop", fill="right") %>%
            left_join(., DF2, by="Employee_ID")
```

#### Output

```
  Employee_ID   Event_1   Event_2  Event_3 Hire_Date Salary
1           1 Pay Raise Promotion Transfer    1/2/06  50000
2           2  Data Cor      <NA>     <NA>    4/6/15 100000
3           3     Raise   New Sup     <NA>   7/23/97 120000
```